# reading the association relationship

Tags: uml, class-diagram, relationships

I read the [illustrated relationship](http://postimage.org/image/t7xfk2myj/) as:Class A associated with class B

So,what is the meaning of :

1) +class B at the end of association

2)0..1

Now,how can I read the relationship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

completely agree with @Wolfgang Fahl and @Idan Arye

Here some elaboration

1)your question touches the Association ends and in your case the

*visibility* (+)followed by *role-name*(class B)

> An association end specifies the role that the object at one end of a
>   relationship performs. Each end of a relationship has properties that
>   specify the role of the association end, its multiplicity, visibility,
>   navigability, and constraints.

2)to be more involved,look at the following class diagram:

[image]

customer may have many reservation

but each reservation owns by one customer

Hope this help you

Answer (score 1):

2) - for each instance of A there can be 0 or 1 instances of B associated with it.

Comment: thank you for kind reply how can i read +Class B at the end of relationship?

Comment: I've never seen something like this before. Where is this illustration from?

Comment: i use Modelio tool http://www.modelio.org/, so when i draw association it appears to me

Comment: I looked abit in the Modelio manual, and I believe it's just a label Modelio adds, and has no formal UML meaning.

Answer (score 1):

the + denotes the visibility of the role. "+" is public. private would be shown as "-". The name of the role is classB which is the name of the class the role belongs to in lower case.